# Eslint: disable all rules except 1 rule?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I want to use Eslint to check the output of my minifier. Obviously, this would trigger a lot of errors. I'm only interested in a single rule (`compat/compat`). How can I disable all the other ones?

Edit:

Here's my `.eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: ['plugin:compat/recommended'],
  env: {
    browser: true,
  },
};
```

Edit:

I found the `reset` option in the docs, but it seems to be disabled for my installation:

```
$ npx eslint file.js --config .eslintrc.browserslist.js --quiet --reset
Invalid option '--reset' - perhaps you meant '--ext'?
$ npx eslint --version
v6.8.0
$ npx eslint -h
eslint [options] file.js [file.js] [dir]

Basic configuration:
  --no-eslintrc                   Disable use of configuration from .eslintrc.*
  -c, --config path::String       Use this configuration, overriding .eslintrc.* config options if present
  --env [String]                  Specify environments
  --ext [String]                  Specify JavaScript file extensions - default: .js
  --global [String]               Define global variables
  --parser String                 Specify the parser to be used
  --parser-options Object         Specify parser options
  --resolve-plugins-relative-to path::String  A folder where plugins should be resolved from, CWD by default

Specifying rules and plugins:
  --rulesdir [path::String]       Use additional rules from this directory
  --plugin [String]               Specify plugins
  --rule Object                   Specify rules

Fixing problems:
  --fix                           Automatically fix problems
  --fix-dry-run                   Automatically fix problems without saving the changes to the file system
  --fix-type Array                Specify the types of fixes to apply (problem, suggestion, layout)

Ignoring files:
  --ignore-path path::String      Specify path of ignore file
  --no-ignore                     Disable use of ignore files and patterns
  --ignore-pattern [String]       Pattern of files to ignore (in addition to those in .eslintignore)

Using stdin:
  --stdin                         Lint code provided on <STDIN> - default: false
  --stdin-filename String         Specify filename to process STDIN as

Handling warnings:
  --quiet                         Report errors only - default: false
  --max-warnings Int              Number of warnings to trigger nonzero exit code - default: -1

Output:
  -o, --output-file path::String  Specify file to write report to
  -f, --format String             Use a specific output format - default: stylish
  --color, --no-color             Force enabling/disabling of color

Inline configuration comments:
  --no-inline-config              Prevent comments from changing config or rules
  --report-unused-disable-directives  Adds reported errors for unused eslint-disable directives

Caching:
  --cache                         Only check changed files - default: false
  --cache-file path::String       Path to the cache file. Deprecated: use --cache-location - default: .eslintcache
  --cache-location path::String   Path to the cache file or directory

Miscellaneous:
  --init                          Run config initialization wizard - default: false
  --env-info                      Output execution environment information - default: false
  --no-error-on-unmatched-pattern  Prevent errors when pattern is unmatched
  --debug                         Output debugging information
  -h, --help                      Show help
  -v, --version                   Output the version number
  --print-config path::String     Print the configuration for the given file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add `root: true` to the config file, that way it will not inherit the other config files.
The `eslint.json` file should look like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  rules: {
    semi: ["error", "always"],
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use your .eslintrc file to keep your configuration (parser, plugin settings, etc), you can use [eslint-nibble](https://github.com/IanVS/eslint-nibble) with the `--rule=compat/compat` flag.  This will respect your normal configuration, but only show you errors from that one rule.

Disclaimer: I'm the creator of eslint-nibble.

Answer (score 0):

Simply specify the rule you want to use in your ESLint config, for instance this would enable only the "semi" rule:

```
module.exports = {
    "rules": {
        "semi": ["error", "always"],
    }
};
```

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules

Or you could specify it with the --rule flag

Comment: That doesn't work, it's spitting out thousands of errors

Comment: What exactly does your eslint config look like? By default, ESLint doesn't have any rules enabled. You enable them either by extending a ruleset or specifying rules.

Comment: Oh I see your problem. In your config 'extends' is loading the rules enabled by default for that plugin., you want to do something like: module.exports = { "plugins":[ "compat" ], "rules": { "compat/compat": "error" }} probably

Answer (score 0):

Eslint's parser options currently default to `ecmaVersion: 5`[1]. So in case, your code is using ECMAScript > 5, eslint will start enforcing the rules of ECMAScript 5, 6, and so on. Hence, apart from defining `root: true`, it's important finding the right `ecmaVersion`. An ideal eslint config for projects beyond ECMAScript 5 that has all eslint rules disabled looks as follows:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 9
  },
  rules: {}
};
```

Where `parserOptions.ecmaVersion` is tuned to the code base's ECMAScript version.

- 1: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-parser-options