How to have ESLint check for only one rule without config file and infile config?
For a legacy project, running ESLint is not yet meaningful as there are way too many errors.
Yet, as a first step for improvement, I want to check for one rule and one rule only, e.g. no-console.
ESLint is installed globally, and now I want a single-line command to check my codebase only for errors of that one rule.
I don't want to create any config file, nor should anything else be installed/added in that project.
npm init @eslint/config@latest creates a config file with way too many rules applied, and it also installs packages in the current project.
The repository shall remain completely unaware that eslint exists, so I don't want these files and folders:

eslint.config.mjs
node_modules/
package-lock.json
package.json

I thought that:
eslint --no-config-lookup --rule "no-console: error"  ./my_js_folder/

would do what I wanted, yet I see other errors for other rules as well, e.g.:

es/no-global-this
unicorn/no-typeof-undefined
valid-jsdoc

Even some warnings pop up, like:
35628:25  warning  Unused eslint-disable directive (no problems were reported from 'no-new')

I was expecting only errors for usage of console.log, console.warn, console.error, etc.
How do I achieve that?

It turns out that the additonal rules were added by comments within javascript files.
Example: some.js:
console.log('this should be reported');

/* eslint quotes: ["error", "double"], curly: 2 */

const thisShouldNotBeReported = 'this is unexpected';

eslint  --no-config-lookup --rule "no-console: error" some.js

eslint_example/some.js
  1:1   error  Unexpected console statement  no-console
  1:13  error  Strings must use doublequote  quotes
  5:33  error  Strings must use doublequote  quotes

✖ 3 problems (3 errors, 0 warnings)
  2 errors and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.

How to disable the in-file config so that only the rule from the command line is applied?

Have you tried --no-eslintrc?

@jabaa --no-eslintrc does not exist for eslint@9.16, --no-config-lookup does.

What do you mean with "does not exist": https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/command-line-interface#--no-eslintrc

@jabaa eslint --help did not show it. I have eslint@9.16

eslint -h | grep no-eslintrc remains empty. I do see: --no-inline-config and --no-config-lookup

"Debugging details missing" even though that eslint allows for configuration via comments within a javascript file in-file is the very scope of this question? Even though I found the solution?

You wrote "The repository shall remain completely unaware that eslint exists". I have no idea how ESLint rules can be defined while being unaware that eslint exists. The posted answer disables existing rules. It's unclear where the rules come from if the repository doesn't contain any rules. The posted and accepted answer answers a different question.

@jabaa Again, read this: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/19232

This confirms what I say. The actual project contains ESLint rules. This question assumes that no ESLint rules exist. That are two different questions. The accepted answer answers a different question.

@jabaa How can one be unware that eslint rules exists predefined in a legacy project? By the fact that dozen of different developers have worked on the project, by the fact that some 3rd-party dependencies were added to the source containing inline config. There was no tooling in place to check for those rules, yet some javascript file enabled certain rules.

You wrote the question. Why would you write this. That's what I mean with missing debugging details. You described a project without any code. The behavior is impossible for this description.

@jabaa It does not confirm anything. I am the OP. I posted my question. I posted my own solution. I opened the issue on github on eslint. This is seriously strange.

You posted the solution to your actual problem, but the question doesn't describe your actual problem. The answer doesn't answer this question. This question doesn't reproduce the problem. The question doesn't contain a [mcve]. That's probably one reason for the downvotes. You don't need to disable other ESLint rules if there aren't any other ESLint rules. The question makes no sense. You wrote that the repository is unaware of the existence of ESLint.

@jabaa It does. It added the example for that very reason.

Ah, I see what you did there. First, you answered the question, while it wasn't answerable and later you added necessary details that contradict the description. Smart. But the question description and the examples are still contradicting.

@jabaa I will explicate on that if that part wasn't clear

You would have to fix title and description to: "How to disable ESLint inline rules", because your code examples contain inline rules and you want to disable them. I'm pretty sure we can find a duplicate. And if not, this could be a helpful question. But currently, it's contradicting and confusing.

Isn't this now a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/60517701/16540390

@jabaa Almost, https://stackoverflow.com/q/60517701/16540390 assumes a config file.

No, it doesn't assume a config file. It allows a config file and contains your answer without config file.

You need to add:
--no-inline-config        Prevent comments from changing config or rules

Somewhere in your project, you have rules defined as code, and those trigger these error you then see.
This should achieve your goal:
eslint --no-inline-config  --no-config-lookup --rule "no-console: error"  ./my_js_folder/


The question and answer don't make much sense. The question contains "The repository shall remain completely unaware that eslint exists", but the command line arguments only disable existing ESLint rules in the project. Why would ESLint rules exist (either as config file, in package.json, or code comments) if the repository is unaware of the existence of ESLint.

@jabaa I was as surprised as you. I have no idea why those rules are being activated. I can just tell that they are.

@jabaa The issue is very much eslint unexpected behavior. I have posted an issue on their end as well. Maybe that will clarify why my use case is my use case? Otherwise, I do not now how to explain it any better than I have. https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/19232

I assume, that the question doesn't correctly describe your project and that your project actually contains ESLint configuration. That means, that the question isn't reproducible and that this answer doesn't answer the question.

@jabaa And yet my answer SOLVES the issue was experiencing within my legacy project. This is one of those very strange stackoverflow experiences.

I've already explained why answer solves your actual problem but isn't helpful for future users. This answer solves a problem that isn't described in the question but actually exists in your real project. This answer disables all other ESLint but the question assumes that the repository isn't aware of the existence of ESLint.
